# Can I configure tomcat to use different JREs for different WARs?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'm currently running tomcat7 on ubuntu but this question goes for any version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to use multiple JREs in the same Java process;  but it is (ultimately) possible to run different webapps in different Java processes and nevertheless make them appear (to the user) to be the same site.

You could, for example, run 2 Tomcat processes -- on 2 different ports -- and use a single Apache HTTPD in front of them (with 2 AJP connectors).

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer as it was my first instinct to start another Tomcat instance, I just wanted to make sure I was not missing out :)